# Which Portuguese is used on Wikipedia?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Which variant of Portuguese is mainly used on Portuguese Wikipedia - European or Brazilian?

Comment: You are asking for a definition of these. This information re the differences in varieties of Portuguese can be googled and it really not an appropriate question for here especially for a native speaker of Portuguese.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for your remark. But neither am I asking about the differences nor am I a native speaker.

Comment: In written form, besides spelling, there is no much difference if the Brazilian Portuguese is well written. There are also semantic differences just like lift and elevator in English. Comboio and trem (for train).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Wikipedia), because of the number of edits, it's mainly *Brazilian*, but you can write also in *European*.

It's recommended that it be left as is when the edit of the article is about the *flavor*. But I guess Brazilian people edit even with this recommendation.

Historically many requests to open exclusive *European* or *Brazilian* wikis were rejected.

Comment: [it's recommended that it be left as is]

Answer (score 5):

Both, they are basically the same in written form, just like you see in Wikipedia in English, is it more British or more American? When something is different, it is differed like that:

**(entry for "hydrogen")**

> O hidrogénio (pt-PT) ou hidrogênio (pt-BR)...

Just like English:

**(entry for "colour")**

> Color (American English), or colour (Commonwealth English)...

Comment: [written form//it is differed=buzzer] And Commonwealth English is not right.

Comment: Just copied and paste the citation from the Wikipedia page!

Comment: This is particularly common in the articles on movies because the titles are often different.